# Cute coloring problem on a board

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Suppose we color an $n\times n$ square board using $n$ colors exactly $n$ times each. Prove that there is either a column or a row containing at least $\lceil \sqrt n \rceil$ different colors. A friend of mine gave me this problem and I managed to solve it, but I would like to know if there is a neater way.

Regards.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Your statement is ungrammatical.  There *either* a column with a certain property or what?

Comment: You mean "either a column OR a row", right

Comment: As String points out, this is not true as stated. Make each column a single color.

Comment: @DavidPeterson - in that case all rows will contain $n$ colors, so it's still true

Comment: @nbubis My comment pertains to the original question, which has been changed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each color, since it is used $n$ times, is found in at least $2\sqrt{n}$ distinct lines (i.e., rows and columns).  (If it is found in $r$ rows and $c$ columns, then $r c \ge n$; hence $r+c \ge 2\sqrt{n}$.)  Adding these up, the number of distinct (color, line) pairs is at least $2n\sqrt{n}$.  By the pigeonhole principle, then, at least one of the $2n$ lines must contain at least $\sqrt{n}$ (and hence at least $\left\lceil\sqrt{n}\right\rceil$) distinct colors.

Comment: +1 A great pigeonholing.  (And of course,the statement that $rc\geq n$ implies $r+c\geq 2\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ is just the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality in disguise.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I did.

Comment: @user4140: What would constitute a "neater way"? This seems pretty neat to me :).

Comment: Wait, this is wrong. for 5 squares you can use a 3x2 and take away one square to have r+c=5<6

Comment: @user4140: You're right; $rc \ge n$ only implies $r+c \ge 2\sqrt{n}$.  The result is the same, though… I've edited the solution.

Comment: ok, looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I found: Suppose each column contains less than $\lceil \sqrt n\rceil$ different colors. Then that means The number of times a color is repeated per column is at least $n-\lceil \sqrt n \rceil$ So the number of times a number is repeated columnwise through the hole board is at least $n^2-n\lceil\sqrt n\rceil$. Note that if color 1 appears in $k_1$ columns then the number of times it is repeated columnwise is $n-k_i$ so we get $n^2-\sum_{k=1}^nk_i\leq n^2-n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil\rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^nk_i\geq n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil\ $

On the other hand note that the number of times color 1 is repeated row-wise is n minus the number of times a number is repeated the most inside any column. Note if color $1$ is found in $k_1$ columns then the maximum will be at least $\lceil \frac{n}{k_1}\rceil$ So then we must have $n^2-\sum_{k=1}^n\lceil \frac{n}{k_1}\rceil\leq n^2-n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil\rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^n\lceil \frac{n}{k_1}\rceil\geq n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil\ $.

So we must solve $\sum_{k=1}^nk_i\geq n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n\lceil \frac{n}{k_1}\rceil\geq n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil$

Note that making the inequality on the left an equality would help us. So we let $\sum_{k=1}^nk_i= n\lceil \sqrt n \rceil$.

I'm stumped here.